# In TOX, what is the difference between [env] and [testenv]?

Tags: tox

I am working on a fix for tox warnings in my builds:
"WARNING: test command found but not installed in testenv"

NOTE: This is a related question but without explanation: [Tox WARNING:test command found but not installed in testenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642747/tox-warningtest-command-found-but-not-installed-in-testenv)

When I change my tox.ini from [testenv] to [env] the commands run fine without warnings.

I could not find any documentation on [env] vs. [testenv].
Is it that somehow my environment is called ENV vs. TESTENV or am I using the wrapper\parent environment when I specify [env] or ??

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Change from `[testenv]` to `[env]` and `tox` ignores unknown section so the commands are simply not run.

Comment: You should put this as an answer. You're spot on. I see that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tox` [knows nothing](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/3.15.0/config.html) about `[env]`. Change from `[testenv]` to `[env]` and `tox` ignores unknown section so the commands are simply not run.